# Java SQLException with JDBC - SQLITE_MISUSE

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc, twitter4j

I am using SQlite in my Java application. If I run my program it will error at some point.

Sometimes it is a simple exception on other occasions the JVM has a fatal error.

> java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_MISUSE]  Library used incorrectly (out of memory)

---

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006d587ab0, pid=7036, tid=6364
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_73-b02) (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
>    Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.73-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>    Problematic frame:
>    C  [sqlite-3.8.11.2-6df82281-eaf0-4204-a962-ce1e48ddd89f-sqlitejdbc.dll+0x7ab0]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>    C:\Users\UltraMouse\workspace\co.windall.twitter\hs_err_pid7036.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>      http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>    The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>    See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

The code line causing this is

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE id=" + id.toString() + ";");
```

It is not consistent, it happens at a different point (This code is in a loop) each time but it always happens.

Here are both my full source files:
http://pastebin.com/RKKVdNZ8
http://pastebin.com/fVaa93Rk

I run it cleanly each time (I remove the database file). It fails on line 102 in file1 at the moment.

I have no clue what to do :(

And yes those twitter keys work for now but are limited to read access, I left them there so you can try the application out if you need too.

Comment: since the attempts to solve your problem didn't seem to work I'd recommend to work on your exception handling. Don't just catch Exception but it's known subclasses separately. This should help you localize the buggy code. With that you can either solve it yourself or post another question.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see exactly what is wrong, but you should definitely close your statements and `ResultSet`s after each operation.

It is most likely causing the memory leak you are seeing:

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
```

Should be called before each new operation and

```
stmt.close();
```

should be called after each operation. so in summary your main loop should look like this:

```
for (Long id : ids) {
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        st = connection.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("...");

        if (rs.next()) {
            Long ft = rs.getLong("followedThem");
            rs.close();
            st.close();

            st = connection.createStatement();
            String sql = "...";

            if (ft != null && ft == -1) {
                sql = x;
            } else {
                sql = y;
            }

            st.executeUpdate(sql);
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: I did start with it like that, that code is after I mucked around a bit. 
It made no difference having the statement in the loop.

Comment: I tested that out it now errors in the same place with: 
java.sql.SQLException: statement is not executing

Comment: what is the exception now?

Comment: @leumas95 you are still using your statement object to get two different ResultSets. I described the problem in my answer. Try to use a new statement for each ones of your ResultSets.

Comment: @epoch java.sql.SQLException: statement is not executing

Comment: @GilR No im not, I close it after each one if you look, and I only have 1 result set at all. ever time i open a statment it is closed right after and also with the result set

Comment: ok, i think i know whats going on, create your statement with the sql to be executed, and call executeUpdate/Query with no arguments

Comment: @epoch how would I do that? connection.createStatement(); dosent take args.

Comment: @epoch Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: sorry, i was thinking about prepareStatement

Comment: @leumas95 and epoch I still think using a separate statement per ResultSet is at least worth a try.

Comment: @GilR. I still don't know what you mean? I only have 1 result set? Unless I'm going crazy, wouldn't surprise me.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [statement documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)

> only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same
>   time

therefore the reuse of your statement should be the problem because it implicitly closes your other ResultSet

> All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a
>   statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists.

but the loop could in some cases need the already closed ResultSet another time and therefore cause an exception.

---

UPDATED:

1. I would separate the two exception handling of the two statements
2. I would use two statement objects
3. In my code I always check if ResultSets or Statements are != null before attempting to close them.

   ```
   for (Long id : ids) {
       Statement st, st2;
       ResultSet rs;
       Long ft = 0;
       try {
           st = connection.createStatement();
           rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE id=" + id.toString() + ";");

           if (rs.next()) {
               ft = rs.getLong("followedThem");
               if (rs != null)
                   rs.close();
               if (st != null)
                   st.close();
           }
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
           e.printStackTrace();
           System.err.println(id);
           System.exit(0);
       }

       if (ft != 0) {
           try {
               st2 = connection.createStatement();
               String sql = "";

               if (ft != null && ft == -1) {
                   sql="UPDATE User SET followedThem=" + String.valueOf(Instant.now().getEpochSecond()) + " WHERE id=" + id.toString() + ";";
               } else {
                   sql=String.format("INSERT INTO User (id,followedMe,followedThem,unfollowedMe,unfollowedThem,status) " +
                       "VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d);", id, -1, Instant.now().getEpochSecond(), -1, -1, 0);
               }

               st2.executeUpdate(sql);
               if (st2 != null)
                   st2.close();

           } catch (SQLException e) {
               System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
               e.printStackTrace();
               System.err.println(id);
               System.exit(0);
           }
       }
   }
   ```